# Why do we double state the executable name in `execlp`?

Tags: c, exec

To run a command with `execlp` we do

```
execlp("ps", "ps", NULL);
```

A redundancy can be seen here, since we pass `ps` twice. This behavior is consistent across all `exec` variants.

Why does exec want such redundancy? Why isn't it written so that we can simply

```
execlp("ps", NULL);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Other answers have explained that you may provide a different `argv[0]` than the name of the program, but haven't explained *why* you might want to do this.

Some programs behave differently depending on the name that's used to invoke them. A common example is shells, e.g. `sh`, `bash`, and `csh`. They check the first character of `argv[0]`, and if this is `-` they operate as a login shell rather than a regular shell. So when `/bin/login` is invoking the user's login shell, it does something like:

```
execlp("/bin/bash", "-bash", (char*)NULL);
```

This way, `bash` knows that it's being run as part of a login and can behave accordingly. This could have been done using an option parameter, but then every program that might be used as a login shell would have to recognize that option (some special usernames have login shells that aren't really shells, but are other programs, and requiring them to support the same option as real shells might be problematic).

Comment: That's absolutely bizarre.  Why would Linux support both an actual process name and a nominal process name?  Why would supporting a dash in front of the process name be any easier than supporting an argument?

Comment: Example: `sh` and `bash` are links to the same executable. it changes its behavior based on which name you use to run it.

Comment: You can make a symlink to `telnet` with a hostname, and `telnet` will treat this as the destination host. This predated aliases.

Answer (score 4):

The first argument is the path of the file to be executed (`/bin/ls`, `/home/development/myproject/foo`).  The remaining arguments correspond to the `argv` vector passed to `main`.  Imagine typing the following in your shell:

```
$ ./foo bar bletch
```

The executable path is `./foo` - that's the first argument passed to `execlp`.  By convention, `argv[0]` is supposed to be the string used to invoke the program, so the complete `argv` vector is `{"./foo", "bar", "bletch", NULL}`.  Hence,

```
execlp( "./foo",  /* executable path */ 
        "./foo",  /* argv[0] */
        "bar",    /* argv[1] */
        "bletch", /* argv[2] */
        NULL      /* argv[3] */
      );
```

It's possible that you may not want `argv[0]` to be the same as the actual command path (say because the path is aliased or you don't want to expose the exact path), in which case you may use something like

```
execlp( "./secret/path/to/foo", "./foo", "bar", "bletch", NULL );
```

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter *should* match the first one, but it is not *required* to be the same.

According to documentation,

> `argv` is an array of argument strings passed to the new program. By convention, the first of these strings should contain the filename associated with the file being executed.

If you have a compelling reason to hide the name of the file being executed from the program that you are planning to run, you can pass any string you want for the second parameter, including an empty or a `NULL` string:

```
execlp("ps", "<hidden>", NULL);
```

Comment: +1, but why must the reason be compelling? If a program doesn't require to know its own filename, why provide it?

Comment: Is it just because the program may change in the future and programmers tend to rely on this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to give your program the name of the executable as its `argv[0]`.  You could write a program (`rvw11.c` compiled to `rvw11` executable):

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    execlp("sleep", "rip van winkle", "40", (char *)0);
    return 1;
}
```

and you would find that if you run:

```
$ ./rvw11 &
[1] 53034
$ ps
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
  515 ttys000    0:00.07 -bash
  534 ttys002    0:00.09 -bash
  543 ttys003    0:01.15 -bash
  558 ttys004    0:00.32 -bash
53034 ttys004    0:00.01 rip van winkle 40
$
```

So, the name that shows up in the `ps` listing is the value given as `argv[0]` in the argument list, not the name of the executable.  (Demonstration on macOS Sierra 10.12.2, but you'd get a similar result on most Unix-like systems.)

This also demonstrates why it is not necessarily feasible to determine the name of the executable from the argument list.